# Hibernate Exception when using mappedby attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, pojo

I am trying to map between tables in pojo class.But I am getting exception for one attribute.
Pojo Classes

Users:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int userId;
    private Role role;
    private Groups groupId;
    private UserType userType;
    private String userName;
    private Boolean isActive;



    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(int userId, Role role, Groups groupId ,UserType userType, String userName, boolean isActive) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.role = role;
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.userType = userType;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "UserID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RoleID", nullable = false)
    public Role getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GroupId", nullable = false)
    public Groups getGroup() {
        return this.groupId;
    }

    public void setGroup(Groups group) {
        this.groupId = group;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserTypeID", nullable = false)
    public UserType getUserType() {
        return this.userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(UserType userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }

    @Column(name = "UserName", nullable = false)
    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Column(name = "IsActive", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIT")
    public Boolean isIsActive() {
        return this.isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(Boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    }
```

Groups:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Groups")
public class Groups implements java.io.Serializable{

    private int groupId;
    private String groupName;
    private String groupDesc;

    private Set<Users> users = new HashSet<Users>(0);

    public Groups (){

    }

    public Groups(int groupId, String groupName, String groupDesc){
        super();
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.groupName = groupName;
        this.groupDesc = groupDesc;
    }

    public Groups(int groupId, String groupName, String groupDesc, Set<Users> users) {
        super();
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.groupName = groupName;
        this.groupDesc = groupDesc;
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name ="GroupID", nullable = false)
    public int getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(int groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    @Column(name = "GroupName", nullable = false)
    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    @Column(name = "GroupDesc", nullable = false)
    public String getGroupDesc() {
        return groupDesc;
    }

    public void setGroupDesc(String groupDesc) {
        this.groupDesc = groupDesc;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "groupId") //Error
    public Set<Users> getUserse() {
        return this.userse;
    }

    public void setUserse(Set<Users> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }


}
```

I am mapping the correct member variable of Users class. But I am getting exception like this

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target     entity property: com.project.pojo.Users.groupId in com.project.pojo.Groups.users
```

In users pojo I have attributes like role,usertype which are mapped without any exception.Whereas for group I am getting this exception.
Can someone please help me to resolve this exception.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your member variables of classes users and groups
Change the variable name **groupId** to **group** of **Users.pojo** and change **mappedby** attribute to **group** in groups class set method.

This will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Groups` class, you first declared a variable named `users` as a set of `Users`, which is fine. So if you gonna annotate `@OneToMany` on your setters, the name must match the variable name.

Also, in your `Users` table, you created a `Groups` variable and you named it as `groupId`, but in your `Users` table you have a `int` type named `groupId`, this will confuse the heck out of hibernate and causing problems. You should rename it to:

```
private Groups group;
```

So it should be like:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "group")
public Set<Users> getUsers() {
    return this.users;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "group", nullable = false)
public Groups getGroup() {
    return this.group;
}
```

You didn't ask but you need to fix your `RoleID` table also. I don't think you really understand how hibernate ORM works yet, see this:

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Answer (score 0):

It must be because of difference between **users** and **userse**.

Answer (score 0):

You defined getter for the Group object in Users bean as:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GroupId", nullable = false)
    public Groups getGroup() {
        return this.groupId;
    }
```

which is not the best accessor name for a bean.

Try renaming the Group object in Users from `groupID` to `group` and change the mapping annotation into something like:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "group")
    public Set<Users> getUserse() {
        return this.userse;
    }
```